# Create a setter that updates a dom element with the new value?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make a setter that will update a DOM element whenever a property of the object is changed?

Comment: Note: I actually asked something different and suddenly realized it didn't make sense. I've updated the question to make it meaningful and preserve the current answer from @MattGreer, so it can be helpful to someone searching for those terms in a future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. Without creating the setter, then `x` will be a plain jane property hanging off the object with no way of knowing when it has changed. Why do you want to avoid the setter? It's a pretty clean way to accomplish your goal.

But one small thing to keep in mind, `Object.defineProperty`, although more verbose, is more supported and "won" over `set` and `get`:

```
a = {};
Object.defineProperty(a, 'x', {
    get: function() {
        return this._x;
    },
    set: function(newX) {
        this._x = newX;
        $("#my_element").html(newX);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh no, actually I was confused with the behavior of the setter. This question makes no sense anymore. Sigh this always happens to me, that sudden enlightenment as soon as I post a question.